# Send a value to another page on link click

Tags: jquery

I have this link that serves to send a value to another page to delete a record:

```
<a href="supp.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'" class="link"><img src="../images/supp.png" width="25" height="25"  title="Delete"/></a>
```

What I want to do is to send value using jQuery-ajax, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
$(this).find('.link').click(function() {
var ID= $(this).find('.link').val();    
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../admin/supp.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
    $('.info').show().html("<img src='../images/success.png' width='30px' height='35' />").fadeOut();
    }
});
return false;           
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

val() is used for input elements not for "a". Check the below,

```
$('.link').click(function() {
var ID= $(this).attr('rel');     
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../administrator/supp.php",
    data: {'id':ID},
    success: function(){
    $('.info').show().html("<img src='../images/success.png' width='30px' height='35' />").fadeOut();
    }
});
return false;           
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" rel="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" class="link"><img src="../images/supp.png" width="25" height="25"  title="Delete"/></a>
```

Comment: what you are expecting to do? ajax or page redirect. Use error handling.

Comment: what if I have two variable to pass in the `rel`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your key value in rel or someother attribute then get key value from that attribute using

```
$("CSS Selector").attr("thatAttribute");
```

Secondly what do you mean by "this"

```
$(this).find('.link')
```

You can simply do this

```
$(".link").click(function(){});
```

Third you send data in ajax using key value pairs

```
data : {
   param1: 'value1',
   param2: $("css form element selector").val(),
   param3: $(".link").attr("rel"), // << this one for your case
}
```